# Powershell pipes and regular expressions, order of evaluation

Tags: regex, powershell, pipeline

This piece of code actually works, and I'm curious whether I got lucky(!?) and found a bug in the Power Shell language (this is pseudo code-ish, but it illustrates my question):

```
$regex = "prefix([0-9]+)"
$collection = Get-Collection | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $regex} `
                             | ForEach-Object { [int] $Matches[1] }
```

Input is basically objects whose property `Name` may be on the format "prefix[Integer]". If that is the case, I want to extract that integer and insert it into a new sequence.

This seemingly works, but it feels like I'm exploiting an implementation detail in the Power Shell language.

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: What is Get-Collection?  Did you create this as a function, or is it just that I cannot find this cmdlet in my PowerShell?

Comment: It's an arbitrary command returning a sequence of objects. The particular function I'm working with is Get-AzureVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that each pipeline expression is a closure.

`Where-Object` is only going to send the Item that matched down the pipeline, not the context.

The simplest to understand method is to do:

```
Get-Collection | ForEach-Object { if($_.Name -match $regex) { [int] $Matches[1] } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not exploiting anything here, it looks perfectly valid to me.

1. You get a collection of objects
2. You filter out the ones which match your regex using `Where-Object`
3. You pass the filtered objects to a `ForEach-Object` loop which simply states the regex match in the pipeline as an integer.

Perfectly normal code. What's the problem?